# get specific table row data in foreach(item in model) loops

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i im using a foreach(item in model) loop inside a  to create table rows that containt the item properties. i'm trying to get a script that works when i click on every button inside the table row to add them to my localstorage. I can manage to change the colors of the clicked button but am unable to get all the data from the td.
here is the code:

```
<table class="table" id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Exercise Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Number of repetitions
            </th>
            <th>
                Number of series
            </th>
            <th>
                Image
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="exercise" id="exercise-@item.IdExercise">
                <td class="exerciseName">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExerciseName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="exerciseForm" style="font-size:20px;" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="exerciseForm" style="font-size:20px;" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="@Url.Content(item.ImageLink01)" alt="Image" style="max-height:300px;max- 
                     width:300px;" class="exerciseImage01" />
                    <img src="@Url.Content(item.ImageLink02)" alt="Image" style="max-height:300px; max- 
                     width:300px; display:none;" class="exerciseImage02" />
                </td>
                <td id="inputAdd">
                    <button id="btn-@item.IdExercise" class="button" style="background-color: rgb(13, 
                     194, 255);" onclick="AddExercise(@item.IdExercise)">Ajouter</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
    </table>


    <script>
        function AddExercise(id_exercise) {

            var button = document.getElementById("btn-" + id_exercise);

            if (button.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(13, 194, 255)") {

                button.style.backgroundColor = "#24bd26";

            }
            else {
                button.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(13, 194, 255)";
                localStorage.removeItem("exercise-" + id_exercise);
            }

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: What data are you needing specifically? Really not clear what specific problem is here. Note you probably wnt to learn about using `data-` attributes which can be read by Element.dataset

Comment: i would like to get all the td from the table row. so i would need something like var exercise= document.getElementById("tablerow").cells; to be able to finally a localstorage.setitem("name",exercise);

Comment: Click on button aand move up to `closest('tr')` and don't need id. Or use data- attribute to put row id on button

Comment: for some reason there is no closest function attributed to a button and since i have 69 buttons with different id's i can't really write a addEventListener without a id param.

Comment: Every element has a closest() method

Comment: i found a solution. Instead of passing and object through the script i just placed a id on every field and passed just the id so that i could take the fileds with a document.getelementbyid on the other side !